# How can I log information specific to the "Too many connections error" in mysql

Tags: mysql

When the Too many connections error is thrown does mysql log that somewhere so later I can see what caused the error? I know I can use commands like "SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS" and "SHOW PROCESSLIST" when that error is happening to troubleshoot, but this is happening sometimes when I am not around to look at it.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using a metric collection system (e.g. Cacti, Munin, Ganglia, Graphite) that covers all your key services and then you can correlate the high number of connections with other service use (e.g. busy httpd workers). You should also set an alert so that if you are at 90% of your MySQL max_connections you'll be notified.